# why does ghc-mod powered neco-ghc only works on project root directory?

Tags: haskell, vim, cabal, ghc-mod

I'm new to haskell so I don't have deep understanding about how `ghc-mod` works and how `cabal-install`-like build tools of haskell worlds move under the hood.

But I somehow found vim haskell plugins from github, including [neco-ghc](https://github.com/eagletmt/neco-ghc) auto completion plugin powered by `ghc-mod` which seemed very attractive to me.

The problem was that it only works on project-level haskell source codes of `cabal-install` initialized projects while it doesn't work at all on `stack`-initialized projects.

My directory structure is generated by following commands:

```
~ $ mkdir my_project && cd my_project
~/my_project $ cabal init
~/my_project $ cabal sandbox init
```

which yields

```
my_project  
|-- Setup.hs  
|-- cabal.sandbox.config  
|-- src / Lib.hs
```

Autocompletion works (it suggests Prelude module's keywords) when I edit `Setup.hs` but I suggests nothing when I try edit `src/Lib.hs`.

My `:NecoGhcDiagnotics` command outputs

```
Current filetype: haskell                                                                                                                                                                                                    
ghc-mod is executable: 1                                                                                                                                                                                                     
omnifunc: necoghc#omnifunc                                                                                                                                                                                                   
neocomplete.vim: 0                                                                                                                                                                                                           
neocomplcache.vim: 2                                                                                                                                                                                                         
YouCompleteMe: 0                                                                                                                                                                                                             
vimproc.vim: 900                                                                                                                                                                                                             
ghc-mod: 5.4.0.0                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Imported modules: Prelude                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Number of symbols in Prelude: 0
```

when I edit `src/Lib.hs` while

```
Current filetype: haskell                                                                                                                                                                                                    
ghc-mod is executable: 1                                                                                                                                                                                                     
omnifunc: necoghc#omnifunc                                                                                                                                                                                                   
neocomplete.vim: 0                                                                                                                                                                                                           
neocomplcache.vim: 2                                                                                                                                                                                                         
YouCompleteMe: 0                                                                                                                                                                                                             
vimproc.vim: 900                                                                                                                                                                                                             
ghc-mod: 5.4.0.0                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Imported modules: Distribution.Simple, Prelude                                                                                                                                                                               
Number of symbols in Prelude: 235
```

is the output of the command when I'm editing `Setup.hs`.

It clearly looks like `ghc-mod` is not detecting any symbols when I'm editing `src/Lib.hs`.. why is this happening?

Comment: Because `ghc-mod` 5.4.0 insists to be [run from the project's root directory](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-mod-5.4.0.0/changelog).  It isn't that it doesn't know how to find the root directory and `chdir()` to it: it specifically wants you to do it beforehand.  Some day, `ghc-mod` authors might begin to grasp the concept of backwards compatibility, and why some people make such a big fuss about it.  That day seem pretty far away for now.

Comment: Upgrading `neco-ghc` [should help](https://github.com/eagletmt/neco-ghc/pull/56).

Comment: @lcd047 Jesus you are my life saver! Why don't you leave those comments as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posting an answer as requested: `ghc-mod` 5.4.0 insists to be [run from the project's root directory](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-mod-5.4.0.0/changelog).  This breaks various third-party programs that depend on `ghc-mod`.  The `neco-ghc` plugin has been [updated](https://github.com/eagletmt/neco-ghc/pull/56) to cope with that, other programs are [dropping support for `ghc-mod`](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/issues/1576).